# Getting a selection in 3ds Max into a list in Python

Tags: python, 3dsmax, maxscript

I am writing in Python, sometimes calling certain aspects of maxscript and I have gotten most of the basics to work. However, I still don't understand FPValues. I don't even understand while looking through the examples and the max help site how to get anything meaningful out of them. For example:

```
import MaxPlus as MP
import pymxs

MPEval = MP.Core.EvalMAXScript
objectList = []

def addBtnCheck():
    select = MPEval('''GetCurrentSelection()''')
    objectList.append(select)
    print(objectList)

MPEval('''
try (destroyDialog unnamedRollout) catch()
rollout unnamedRollout "Centered" width:262 height:350
(
    button 'addBtn' "Add Selection to List" pos:[16,24] width:88 height:38 
    align:#left

    on 'addBtn' pressed do
        (
            python.Execute "addBtnCheck()"
        )
)
''')
MP.Core.EvalMAXScript('''createDialog unnamedRollout''')
```

(I hope I got the indentation right, pretty new at this)

In the above code I successfully spawned my rollout, and used a button press to call a python function and then I try to put the selection of a group of objects in a variable that I can control through python.

The objectList print gives me this:

```
 [<MaxPlus.FPValue; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Autodesk::Max::FPValue *' at 0x00000000846E5F00> >]
```

When used on a selection of two objects. While I would like the object names, their positions, etc!

If anybody can point me in the right direction, or explain FPValues and how to use them like I am an actual five year old, I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Where to start, to me the main issue seems to be the way you're approaching it:

- why use MaxPlus at all, that's an low-level SDK wrapper as unpythonic (and incomplete) as it gets
- why call maxscript from python for things that can be done in python (getCurrentSelection)
- why use maxscript to create UI, you're in python, use pySide
- if you can do it in maxscript, why would you do it in python in the first place? Aside from faster math ops, most of the scene operations will be orders of magnitude slower in python. And if you want, you can import and use python modules in maxscript, too.

Comment: Haha alright alright, you make really good points and I don't really have an answer for any of them. I started coding recently, teaching myself python and saw that max could use python. (I am first and foremost a 3D modeler.) So I thought to myself, oh there is this small script I have always wanted to write. Lets do it in python to test myself!


But to get to a few of your points:
I thought I had to use MaxPlus to get to certain functions I need. And I used the rollout in max because that's what I know and I have been having soooo much trouble trying to install pyside2.

Comment: I just found a previous comment of yours on an Autodesk forum and your website with tips regarding code that will probably be very useful to me. So Im going to study up a bit on that and pymxs! Again thanks :)

Comment: Unless you need some very low-level stuff, you don't need MaxPlus. And even if you need them, the .NET SDK API is also accessible from maxscript. It has some limitations but so does MaxPlus. As for pySide, you don't need to install anything, that's a part of max install. See scripts\Python\demoPySide scripts for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
import MaxPlus as MP
import pymxs

mySel = mp.SelectionManager.Nodes
objectList = []

for each in mySel:
    x = each.Name
    objectList.append(x)

print objectList
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is with the

```
my_selection = rt.selection
```

command...

However, I've found it works a little better for me to throw it into a list() function as well so I can get it as a Python list instead of a MAXscript array. This isn't required but some things get weird when using the default return from rt.selection.

```
my_selection = list(rt.selection)
```

Once you have the objects in a list you can just access its attributes by looking up what its called for MAXscript.

```
for obj in my_selection:
    print(obj.name)
```